# Executing php script in terminal give Permission denied error

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I have a php script. It works fine on web server. I need to execute it on linux terminal. Then it gives Php warning Permission denied.

Any one can help me?

linux command:

```
usr/bin/php /var/www/site/myscript.php
```

php script

```
<?php
$text = "Cats chase mice";
$filename = "somefile.txt";
$fh = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($fh, $text);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? What are the permissions of the script (i.e. output of "ls -l <scriptname>")? Also, is the error citing a specific line number in your script?

Comment: What user are you logged into by the terminal? What are the permissions of the file you are trying to write to? If it doesn't exist, what are the permissions of the parent directory?

Comment: @ravindra answers belong in an Stack Overflow answer, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

In browser php file/scripts run as www-data permission.
But in CLI you may be running as normal user.You can change permission of file by adding normal user as owner.
May be you also need to change permission for directory too.

Answer (score 0):

check it

```
sudo usr/bin/php /var/www/site/myscript.php
```

Comment: this will write file with super user. This is not recommended.

Comment: Sudo might not even be installed

Answer (score 0):

You need some permissions to write files.

If you are sure the script is harmless you can do :

```
sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/site/myscript.php
```

Otherwise, you could create the file and give it to the user who will launch the script :

```
touch somefile.txt && chown [user] somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should check permissions to /var/www/site/somefile.txt - it seems like You can not write to somefile.txt. You can do chown on that file, or try run the command as root (not recommended)